# Why is single-point series grounding avoided in resolving ground-loop problems?

Tags: grounding, ground-loop

[image]

It appears that using single point series grounding, there is some additive effect
$$
V_{c}-\mathrm{what's\;accounted\;from\;Circuit\;1\;and\;2}
$$
My question is if this approach is closest to what happens in many homes, then why is it said to be a bad approach and must be avoided?

Comment: In homes all loads are parallel to each other.

Comment: Because in a home, your TV doesn't care if it sees 1 or 2V less while you're using the kettle. In electronic circuits however, your sensitive analog filter might care a lot about the 100 or 200mV of noise your microcontroller causes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If this is a diagram of house wiring and it has been installed with the correct wire gauges, the various ground impedances \$Z_1, Z_2, Z_3\$ are insignificant and will not effect the operation of the various appliances. In any case many houses are not wired like this. There will be multiple feeds to different areas and for different purposes (lighting, power, special one-off circuits etc) only joining up at the distribution panel. Some countries, like the UK, use what is called a ring main where both ends of the feed are taken back to the distribution panel.

On the other hand if your diagram is for, say, a HiFi system with sensitive low level signals, then the ground impedances can become very significant. Solutions such as star earthing would be used.

Answer (score 3):

### You are confusing neutral and ground.

This is a common affliction of people who come from electronics, where "ground" is the word for Vss, "common" or the mysterious backplane which magically returns all current.

AC mains isn't anything like that.

### Neutral is dedicated to its partner live/hot.

In AC mains, the concept of "Vss" or "Common" is abolished altogether.  Each return-current path is hardwired as a dedicated wire called "Neutral".   It is separately and specifically engineered to task, and is provided circuit breaker protection in a very sneaky way, which in turn **requires** that neutral be wired correctly in relation to the live/hot wires.  As you know, live/hot wires have circuit breaker protection; neutral doesn't need a circuit breaker since it serves only loads served by the partner hot/live wire.

So any given AC circuit has a dedicated full loop: a live wire and a dedicated neutral wire to that one live wire.  It can't be any other way because the live wire is run at near thermal limits for economy's sake, and that means, so is the neutral.  You are putting 16A on 2.5mm2 wire, or 20A on 12 AWG cable... which is about the limit for a cable that may be run with other cables and packed in wall insulation.

And boy, do we have the science on that!  NFPA does science to death, and the result is the National Electrical Code or *El NEC*.

Each circuit's live and neutral wire come back (together, for magnetic field reasons) to the consumer unit/service panel, where the live lands on a breaker, and the neutral lands on a breaker or the neutral bar.  The breaker is fed from either a bus bar or a fork assembly linking many breakers to the master breaker or RCBO.

So these resistances you are describing, Z1, Z2 and Z3, are inconsequential - perhaps an inch of very thick bus bar rated for worst case ampacity of the entire panel.

### Ground, though

Ground aka Earth is entirely a safety shield designed to catch fault current and allow it to go back to the panel at whatever current it wants to flow. This means a fault will cause immediate circuit breaker trip.

Ground/earth is entirely separated from all conductors (live and neutral) in every single place in the system.  Except, obviously, for the aforementioned fault condition.   In *El NEC* countries there is, however, an equipotential bond tying neutral to ground at the main point of service entry, to keep neutral from floating thousands of volts above earth.  In fact, this bonding is what makes neutral *neutral*.  Contrast with urban Philippines, which has no neutral and has 220V with center grounding (110V live to ground).